# Google Drive PHP API Client: Creating a folder in a shared drive

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to create a folder in a newly created shared drive, using Google's PHP API Client with the following code (Note the API connection and service is all working without issue):

```
//Create the drive
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive_Drive();
$drive->setName( "Drive Name" );

$create_drive_response = $service->drives->create( uniqid(), $drive );
$drive_id = $create_drive_response->id;     


//Create the folder
$folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$folder->setName ( "Folder Name" );
$folder->setMimeType ( 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' );
$folder->setDriveId ( $drive_id );

$optional_params = [ 'supportsAllDrives' => true];

$create_folder_response = $service->files->create( $folder, $optional_params );
$folder_id = $create_folder_response->id()
```

The drive creates without issue, and the folder creates without issue, but no matter what I do, the folder always gets created in the root of My Drive, and not in the newly created drive. There are no errors or warnings in the response.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation doesn't mentioned this anywhere, but when creating a folder or file in a shared drive you need to set both the 'driveId' property and the 'parents' property to the ID of the shared drive using `$folder->setParents ( $drive_id );`:

```
//Create the drive
$drive = new Google_Service_Drive_Drive();
$drive->setName( "Drive Name" );

$create_drive_response = $service->drives->create( uniqid(), $drive );
$drive_id = $create_drive_response->id;     


//Create the folder
$folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$folder->setName ( "Folder Name" );
$folder->setMimeType ( 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' );
$folder->setDriveId ( $drive_id );
$folder->setParents ( $drive_id );

$optional_params = [ 'supportsAllDrives' => true];

$create_folder_response = $service->files->create( $folder, $optional_params );
$folder_id = $create_folder_response->id();
```

Comment: Note: As of June 1st, 2020 the 'supportsAllDrives' parameter is depreciated and all applications are assumed to support shared drives. https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource.html#_create

Comment: Got it to work with `$folder->setParents([$drive_id]);` (`parents` should be an array of ids).

Comment: AND INCLUDING the `supportsAllDrives` parameter.